# Parse.com javascript SDK persist cloud authentication client side

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an app build with parse, and i have stumbled on to a issue.

I want cloud logged in users to be logged in client side, when the user logs in, he is redirected to another page, this page contains some client side javascript, with some object updates, creations, etc, the objects in question, have permissions set on to them, an avg user cannot perform these actions, the cloud login session, does not seem to persist to the client SDK. Since i am getting:

```
{"code":119,"error":"This user is not allowed to perform the create operation on Station. You can change this setting in the Data Browser."}
```

On a cloud authenticated user, with sufficient permissions.

I know i could remove the permissions, and hide my API keys from unauthenticated users, but if i remove the permissions on the objects, JS elsewhere would be able to create/delete etc.

If the question is not clear enough, feel free to ask for elaboration, i will do my best.

Can i remove the permissions and create a beforeUpdate, beforeDelete etc in the cloud, and check if the user is authenticated there?

Comment: What do you mean by "cloud logged in users"? Parse is designed around the idea of people logging in at the client, and their credentials (a secure token) are included with cloud requests so you don't need to log them in "in the cloud".

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by logging in client side, and server side .... rewriting my code to pure client side JS atm, i guess this could be a common pitfall to people new with Parse, server side initiated sessions and client side initiated sessions are not shared.